# we have two table and we want to fetch that data of table1 which is not in table2

Tags: rdbms

I have two different tables with `ID` and `name` columns ( specified below). How can I retrieve records from `table1` where `ID` does not exist in `table2` ?

table1

```
ID          name
---         -----
1           ani
2           bni
3           cini
4           dani
```

table2

```
ID          name
---         -----
1           ani
5           eni
```

output

```
ID          name
---         -----
2           bni
3           cini
4           dani
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of the RDBMS databases, functionality to find these kind of records exists. There are different ways to identify records ( either using LEFT JOIN or NOT IN or provided functions like `NOT EXISTS` ), below mentioned option is more performant than others:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
)
```

Answer (score -1):

**SQL: MINUS Operator**

> SELECT name FROM table1 MINUS SELECT name FROM table2;

This may helps

Comment: how  can we do it using left join because MINUS does not work on Mysql,SQL server.